# When Mysql chose to kill a Process(automatically)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I faced some real issues regarding the execution of some stored procedures using Mysql server. Sometimes, one of my procedures is not executed (or maybe stopped) during an external call (from app) so I'm wondering :

- Is it possible that Mysql could stop automatically the and kill the
  process?
- if is it true, what are the indicators and factors that make Mysql
  chose its victim?
- Is there an alternative to set up a list of priority of running
  queries?

Thanks.

Comment: it is a general question to define some scenarios when Mysql decide to kill automatically a ps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL can kill a *connection* if it exceeds `wait_timeout`.  (Caution, there are various wait timeout settings.)

InnoDB can kill a *transaction* in the case of a "deadlock".  One of the competing transactions is killed, the other(s) are allowed to continue.

InnoDB can kill a *query* if it is waiting too long for a lock.  See `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`, which defaults to 50 seconds.

A *user* can "kill" a mysql process via the commandline tool 'mysql' and it's `kill` command.

I don't think there is anything special about Stored Procedures, Functions, Events, Triggers -- they are essentially collections of queries that are, in turn, subject to the comments above.

`UDFs` contain code written by users and specially installed.  These can do anything nasty that you like.

There are essentially no "priorities" that you can control.  It is better to let MySQL decide what to do when.

Do you mean something else by "process"?